# Adding jquery AJAX to send string into python script

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

How can i send a simple string, called accessToken (from Facebook API), to my python script? Is my way of thinking correct?

```
$.ajax({
traditional: true,
type: "POST",
url: my server ip:port?,
data: accessToken,
success: ok,
dataType: "String"
});
```

Lets say that python script will work on my local PC, should i then just tell my script to listen to POST requests on a given port? Does the string need any additional processing? I am not sure about whether this is correct, because it is my first time setting any ajax calls, or serverside python scripts, therefore i have, for now, no way to check whether this works.

Comment: The data would generally be key/value pairs, so unless `accessToken` is already set up like that you might instead be looking for something like: `data: { token: accessToken }`  Then your server-side code would get the value of `accessToken` from the posted values using the key `"token"`.

Comment: but if i do it as key:value pair, shouldnt i change dataType to "json" and then parse json in python?

Comment: What is the value of `accessToken` currently?  If it's just a string value, then you'd need a key to go with that value for the HTTP request.

Comment: var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken; from fbAPI, so i presume it is an object, but i could then just String(accessToken) to send it, right?

Comment: It sounds like your first step should really be to get your environment up and running so you can start testing these things.  Contemplating whether or not things should work isn't going to get you far.  `"i have, for now, no way to check whether this works"` - That's the first problem to be solved.